# It is possible to run the reindex of a single catalog price rule in a module controller for example?

Tags: magento2, reindex, catalog-rules

The idea behind it, is some how keep a track of what's catalog rules are indexed. If i can run the index of a single rule in a module i can then save some logs and also do them in blocks of 10 for example

Answer (score 0):

Extending upon this answer, here are some more details on how to reindex, how to get the IDs, and reindexing only what is needed.

ReindexAll can add a lot of overhead, especially on very large catalogs/sites.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->eavConfigFactory = $eavConfigFactory;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
    $this->indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Then, when you want to use it:

```
public function ensureIndexersAreReady()
{
    $indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create();
    $indexerCollection = $this->indexerCollectionFactory->create();

    $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $idx = $indexer->load($id);
        if ($id == 'catalogrule_product') {
             $idx->reindexAll($id); // this reindexes all
             //$idx->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is $idx? Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory? And what ID should be passed to reindexRow? A Rule ID?

Comment: Answer updated can you check please ?